# Dynamic stylesheet link

Tags: angular

Ive created a component to let me preview a Google Font.  This requires a link to the font style sheet.  I can see the stylesheet gets loaded but the text does not display in the selected font family.

```

```
import { Input, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
selector: 'font-preview',
styles: [
    '.preview { font-family: "{{fontFamily}}"',
    '.title { font-size: 18pt; color: #673ab7;}',
    '.large { font-size: 14pt;}',
    '.normal { font-size: 10pt;}'
    ],
template: `
    <div *ngIf="fontFamily; else noPreview">
        <link [href]="fontLink" rel="stylesheet">
        <div class="preview">
            <div class="title">{{fontFamily}}</div>
            <div class="normal">
            ABCČĆDĐEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSŠTUVWXYZŽ
            abcčćdđefghijklmnopqrsštuvwxyzž
            1234567890‘?’“!”(%)[#]@/&<-+÷×=>®©$€£¥¢:;,.*
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #noPreview>
        Select a font to preview
    </ng-template>
`
})
export class FontPreviewComponent {

    @Input()
    fontFamily: string;

    constructor(
        public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) {}

    get fontLink(): string {
        if (this.fontFamily) {
            return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' + this.fontFamily.replace(' ', '+'));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

```

I sort of understand why this isn't working but I cant think of a work around.
I could use an iframe to a non angular page I guess.... :/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it :)

`<div [style.font-family]="fontFamily">`

No need for the styles.